# Kafka not connecting getting below issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

```
2021-09-09 21:42:40.039  WARN 14636 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mygroup-1, groupId=mygroup] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-09-09 21:42:40.039  WARN 14636 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mygroup-1, groupId=mygroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-09-09 21:42:41.778  WARN 14636 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-09-09 21:42:41.779  WARN 14636 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-09-09 21:42:43.001  WARN 14636 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mygroup-1, groupId=mygroup] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-09-09 21:42:43.002  WARN 14636 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mygroup-1, groupId=mygroup] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-09-09 21:42:44.634  WARN 14636 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-09-09 21:42:44.634  WARN 14636 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-09-09 21:42:45.908  WARN 14636 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mygroup-1, groupId=mygroup] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-09-09 21:42:45.908  WARN 14636 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mygroup-1, groupId=mygroup]
```

Code

```
@Service
public class KafKaConsumerService {
    private final Logger logger = 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafKaConsumerService.class);
 
    @KafkaListener(topics="mytopic", groupId="mygroup")
    public void consumeFromTopic(String message) {
        System.out.println("Consummed message "+message);
    }

}

    public class KafKaProducerService {
    private static final Logger logger = 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafKaProducerService.class);
     
    public static final String topic = "mytopic";
      
      @Autowired 
      private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemp;
      
      public void publishToTopic(String message) {
          System.out.println("Publishing to topic "+topic);
          this.kafkaTemp.send(topic, message);
      }
}
```

properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=mygroup
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Comment: Is your kafka running in local at 9092 port ? could you confirm

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this warning because of below Apache-Kafka configuration

```
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
```

Which means at the time of Spring Boot start consumer try to listen/consume message from   **mytopic** but it's actually not exist.

Please create topic first or change above configuration to

```
KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
```